# Enable SSO for specific domain users

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using OpenID Connect authentication in my app. I have registered my app in Microsoft App Registration Portal and received a Client Id and secret from there.

```
private static string appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppId"];
private static string appSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppSecret"];
private static string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];
private static string graphScopes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:GraphScopes"];

public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = appId,
            Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = "openid email profile offline_access " + graphScopes,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                    // In a real application you would use IssuerValidator for additional checks, 
                    // like making sure the user's organization has signed up for your app.
                    //     IssuerValidator = (issuer, token, tvp) =>
                    //     {
                    //         if (MyCustomTenantValidation(issuer)) 
                    //             return issuer;
                    //         else
                    //             throw new SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException("Invalid issuer");
                    //     },
            },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async(context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;
                        string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                        TokenCache userTokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(signedInUserID,
                            context.OwinContext.Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextBase).GetMsalCacheInstance();
                        ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
                            appId,

                            redirectUri,
                            new ClientCredential(appSecret),
                            userTokenCache,
                            null);
                        string[] scopes = graphScopes.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

                        AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, scopes);
                    },
                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
            }
        });
}
```

This code enables SSO but from any Microsoft account as I have used `common` authority. But I want users from *specific directory or domain* to login into my application.

I have tried this

```
Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}",
```

instead of

```
Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0",
```

But it is not working and Microsoft Login page is not displayed in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but you're missing the `/v2.0` at the end.

For multi-tenant apps (AAD and MSA accounts) you use:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0
```

For *single-tenant*  apps (AAD only) you need to use:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/v2.0
```

The `/v2.0` signifies that your app uses Azure AD's "v2.0 Application Model" (aka "v2 Endpoint").

Comment: There is one more question from my side. Is it possible to enable only user of specific group within some domain to login in my application? If yes, then how I could do that